# I need this piece of Java code to send all the XML files in the directory, is there a way to loop through each XML file

Tags: java, rest-assured

I have a piece of Java restassured code that that pulls top 5 ids from the DB and uses it in an XML file creating 5 XML files.

Then I am picking each xml file from this directory individually and sending it to a server but I need to send them all one by one.

```
public class sendPlaylistAcknowledgment {

Properties prop = new Properties(); // creating prop object as global variable

@BeforeTest

public void getData() throws IOException{

    FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream("D:\\Tools\\Workspace\\BXF\\src\\files\\config.properties"); //creating f object
    prop.load(f); // to load the file object into prop file

    //In the code below we will use the config values set in .property file
}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@Test
public void postData() throws IOException{


    String postData = GenerateStringFromResource("C:\\Users\\shussain\\Desktop\\BXF_Msg\\PlaylistAck\\BXF_1501110072083.XML");
    //BaseURL

    RestAssured.baseURI= prop.getProperty("AISHOST"); //value populating from property methord above

    Response resp = given().log().all().
    header("Content-Type", "application/XML; charset=utf-8").
    body(postData).
    when().
    post("/bxfxml").
    then().assertThat().statusCode(200).and().contentType(ContentType.XML).
    extract().response();

    //to convert raw data to string

    XmlPath xmlResponse= reusableFunctions.rawToXML(resp);
    String responseString = resp.asString();
    System.out.println("XML response is - "+ responseString);

}
 public static String GenerateStringFromResource(String path) throws IOException{

     return new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path)));
 }

}
//Below code pulls data from DB and creates the XML file
public List <String> getExternalId() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, InvalidFileFormatException, IOException{

    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("D:\\Tools\\Workspace\\BXF\\src\\files\\config.properties");
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.load(file);

    Wini ini = new Wini(new File(prop.getProperty("WOINI")));

    String userid = ini.fetch("ConnectionString", "User ID");
    String pwd = ini.fetch("ConnectionString", "Password");
    String dbName = ini.fetch("ConnectionString", "Initial Catalog");
    String connectionURL = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost" + ";databaseName="+dbName + ";user=" +userid + ";password=" +pwd;


    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL);
    System.out.println("Driver version: " + con.getMetaData().getDriverVersion());

    //retrieve data
    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(prop.getProperty("SELECT TOP 5 * FROM WO_INTERFACE_QUEUE WHERE ACTION_INFO = 'Playlist' ORDER BY CREATE_DATE DESC"));

    List <String> externalId = new ArrayList<String>();

    while (rs.next()) {
        externalId.add(rs.getString("INTERFACE_QUEUE_ID"));

        }

    return externalId;

}
   public void createBXFAckFXml(String id) {

          try {
             FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("D:\\Tools\\Workspace\\BXF\\src\\files\\config.properties");
             Properties prop = new Properties();
             prop.load(file);

             DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory =
             DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
             DocumentBuilder dBuilder = 
                dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
             Document doc = dBuilder.newDocument();
             // root element
             Element rootElement = doc.createElement("BxfMessage");
             doc.appendChild(rootElement);

             // setting attribute to element
             rootElement.setAttribute("xmlns:xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
             rootElement.setAttribute("xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
             rootElement.setAttribute("xmlns:xs", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
             rootElement.setAttribute("id", "urn:uuid:427c5fb4-987c-4718-8ace-12fcb835df21");
             rootElement.setAttribute("dateTime", "2017-10-25T09:28:12.1074289-04:00");
             rootElement.setAttribute("messageType", "Acknowledgement");
             rootElement.setAttribute("origin", "ADC");
             rootElement.setAttribute("originType", "Automation System");
             rootElement.setAttribute("userName", "ADC_User");
             rootElement.setAttribute("destination", "WideOrbit");
             rootElement.setAttribute("originMessageId", id);
             rootElement.setAttribute("status", "OK");
             rootElement.setAttribute("ext:usage", "Application Acknowledgement");
             rootElement.setAttribute("xsi:schemaLocation", "http://smpte-ra.org/schemas/2021/2008/BXF bxfschema.xsd http://smpte-ra.org/schemas/2021/2008/BXF/Extension bxfschema-extension.xsd http://www.atsc.org/XMLSchemas/pmcp/2007/3.1 pmcp31.xsd");
             rootElement.setAttribute("xmlns:ext", "http://smpte-ra.org/schemas/2021/2008/BXF/Extension");
             rootElement.setAttribute("xmlns", "http://smpte-ra.org/schemas/2021/2008/BXF");

             // write the content into xml file
             TransformerFactory transformerFactory =
             TransformerFactory.newInstance();
             Transformer transformer =
             transformerFactory.newTransformer();
             DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
             doc.setXmlStandalone(true);
             String filename = prop.getProperty("PLAYLISTACK_ENDPOINT")+ "BXF_"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".XML";
             StreamResult result =
             new StreamResult(new File(filename));
             transformer.transform(source, result);
             // Output to console for testing
             StreamResult consoleResult =
             new StreamResult(System.out);
             transformer.transform(source, consoleResult);
          } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
          }
```

Comment: Second time when xml files wil be generated then previous file will be deleted or renamed ? If not then first you can rename the existing files and after that you can loop through new xml files one by one you can send data .

Comment: For now i am neither renaming it not deleting it. I will take your suggestion and rename it.

Comment: Thanks Deepak, this helped.

Comment: I am happy that my answer helped some one .If you want ypu can accept the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On next run of xml file creating program you can change the extention of previously sent data to something else after that you can loop through the xml files and can send new data

```
   Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get("."),
        path -> path.toString().endsWith(".xml"))
        .forEach(data -> {
          // send you data here
      });
```